# Is there any way to mute a thread in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm looking for a plug-in that will let me mute conversations/threads that once I decide are no longer relevant the plugin would automatically mark the future ones as read. I don't want to set a permanent filter for these but many (and I do mean many) times a day, I get CC'd on conversations I care about in the beginning but then stop caring about the outcome and it would be great to be able to mute them.
If any one knows of anything like that, let me know, if not maybe I'll make an outlook plugin..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming soon in Outlook?

http://news.cnet.com/8301-13860_3-10219256-56.html

In the meantime, this might be what you're after.

http://www.clearcontext.com/personal/

Comment: FWIW, I started using clearcontext today. So far, I'm reasonably impressed. If I think about it, I'll post more thoughts after using it for a while.

Comment: I've been using ClearContext (Personal) now for about a year now. I love it!

Comment: I use ClearContext Professional and it's well worth it, just for the auto-filing and flagging of important conversations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Outlook Rules Wizard to automatically mark the thread read by the subject line.

Answer (score 0):

In case some people are still looking for the answer and have access to Outlook.com, [I posted an answer on the Apple StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356344/111955): select the thread then at the top select `...` then `Ignore`.

Related: [How to archive and mute in Outlook (as in Gmail)?](https://superuser.com/questions/986016/how-to-archive-and-mute-in-outlook-as-in-gmail?rq=1)