# How to archive and mute in Outlook (as in Gmail)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

GMail has buttons to [archive](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en) or [mute](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47787?hl=en) conversations/threads. Is there any equivalent or similar feature in Outlook?

To explain, archiving or muting moves the conversation out of your inbox, but **it still appears in search results** (this is important to me).

> You can remove messages from your Gmail inbox but keep them in the All mail tab by archiving. It’s like moving messages into a filing cabinet instead of putting them in the trash can.

Archiving is temporary, a new message will return the thread to the inbox:

> When someone replies to a message you've archived, the email thread including that message will show up again in your inbox.

Whereas muting is permanent:

> When you mute a conversation, new messages added to the conversation bypass your inbox so that the conversation stays archived.
>
> Muted conversations will only pop back into your inbox ready for your attention if a new message in the conversation is addressed to you and no one else

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that Outlook has identical ways to achieve it.

But it depends on what you're trying to achieve. By default, Outlook only searches a single folder and you can make it to look in all folders by changing the setting to include all folders when searching by going to `File > Options > Search` and then you can apply `always move messages in this conversation` from  the right click menu on the conversation.

If you'd still like to get notified when there is message in the conversation, you can set up a rule for that or you can just simply ignore it.